Empty Poincare Section When The Phase Space Is Full
I have the following Mathematica code for drawing Phase Space:
coordrep = {t -> t[\[Tau]], 
   r -> r[\[Tau]], \[Theta] -> \[Theta][\[Tau]], \[Phi] -> \[Phi][\
\[Tau]], t' -> t'[\[Tau]], 
   r' -> r'[\[Tau]], \[Theta]' -> \[Theta]'[\[Tau]], \[Phi]' -> \
\[Phi]'[\[Tau]]};

lagrangian = -1/(
    2 \[Pi] \[Alpha]) (f[r] t'^2 - r'^2/f[r] - 
      r^2 ((\[Theta]')^2 + Cos[\[Theta]]^2 (\[Phi]')^2) + 
      r^2 \[Eta]^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2) /. coordrep;

Pt = D[lagrangian, t'[\[Tau]]];

Pr = D[lagrangian, r'[\[Tau]]];

P\[Theta] = D[lagrangian, \[Theta]'[\[Tau]]];

P\[Phi] = D[lagrangian, \[Phi]'[\[Tau]]];

hamiltonian = ((Pt t'[\[Tau]] + Pr r'[\[Tau]] + 
         P\[Theta] \[Theta]'[\[Tau]] + P\[Phi] \[Phi]'[\[Tau]]) - 
       lagrangian) /. t'[\[Tau]] -> En /. \[Phi]'[\[Tau]] -> l // 
   Expand;

lag = lagrangian /. t'[\[Tau]] -> En /. \[Phi]'[\[Tau]] -> l;

Needs["VariationalMethods`"]

eqns = EulerEquations[lag, {r[\[Tau]], \[Theta][\[Tau]]}, \[Tau]];

f[r_] = 1 + r^2/(4 \[Lambda]) - 
   r^2/(4 \[Lambda]) Sqrt[
    1 + (8 \[Lambda] (rh^2 + rh^4 + 2 \[Lambda]))/r^4 - 8 \[Lambda]];

En = 20; \[Alpha] = 1/\[Pi]; \[Eta] = 1; l = 10; rh = 1; \[Lambda] = \
-0.1;

sol = Table[
   Block[{a, b, \[Chi], d, habd}, 
    habd = hamiltonian /. \[Tau] -> 0 /. {r[0] -> a, 
       r'[0] -> b, \[Theta][0] -> \[Chi], \[Theta]'[0] -> d}; {a, 
      b, \[Chi]} = {x, 5, 0}; d = d /. FindRoot[habd == En, {d, x}];
    Reap[
     NDSolve[{eqns, r[0] == a, 
       r'[0] == b, \[Theta][0] == \[Chi], \[Theta]'[0] == 
        d(*WhenEvent[\[Theta][\[Tau]]\[Equal]0&&\[Theta]'[\[Tau]]\
\[GreaterEqual]0,Sow[{r[\[Tau]],r'[\[Tau]]}]]*)}, {r[\[Tau]], 
       r'[\[Tau]]}, {\[Tau], 0, 5000}, Method -> Automatic, 
      StartingStepSize -> 1/500, MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]]]], {x, 10, 
    11, 0.2}];

kol = Flatten[sol[[1, 1]], 1];

ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate[{r[\[Tau]], r'[\[Tau]]} /. kol], {\[Tau], 0, 100}, 
 PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1/2]

Which gives me the following result:

But if I try to get the Poincare section using this code:
sol1 = Table[
   Block[{a, b, \[Chi], d, habd}, 
    habd = hamiltonian /. \[Tau] -> 0 /. {r[0] -> a, 
       r'[0] -> b, \[Theta][0] -> \[Chi], \[Theta]'[0] -> d}; {a, 
      b, \[Chi]} = {x, 5, 0}; d = d /. FindRoot[habd == En, {d, x}];
    Reap[
     NDSolve[{eqns, r[0] == a, 
       r'[0] == b, \[Theta][0] == \[Chi], \[Theta]'[0] == d, 
       WhenEvent[\[Theta][\[Tau]] == 0 && \[Theta]'[\[Tau]] >= 0, 
        Sow[{r[\[Tau]], r'[\[Tau]]}]]}, {}, {\[Tau], 0, 5000}, 
      Method -> Automatic, StartingStepSize -> 1/500, 
      MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]]]], {x, 10, 11, 0.2}];

ps = ListPlot[Table[Flatten[sol1[[i]][[2]], 1], {i, Length@sol1}], 
  PlotTheme -> {"Detailed", "NeonColor"}, FrameLabel -> {r, r'}, 
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[.004], ImageSize -> 800, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 20]]

I get an empty solution and plot. What modifications should be made to the code?
Any help in this regard would be truly beneficial!

Please note, that $\theta(\tau)$ is not periodic, therefore from WhenEvent[\[Theta][\[Tau]] == 0 && \[Theta]'[\[Tau]] >= 0,Sow[{r[\[Tau]] we have empty set. To see what we should catch using WhenEvent let visualize $\theta, \theta'$ as follows
coordrep = {t -> t[\[Tau]], 
   r -> r[\[Tau]], \[Theta] -> \[Theta][\[Tau]], \[Phi] -> \[Phi][\
\[Tau]], t' -> t'[\[Tau]], 
   r' -> r'[\[Tau]], \[Theta]' -> \[Theta]'[\[Tau]], \[Phi]' -> \
\[Phi]'[\[Tau]]};

lagrangian = -1/(2  \[Pi]  \[Alpha])  (f[r]  t'^2 - r'^2/f[r] - 
      r^2  ((\[Theta]')^2 + Cos[\[Theta]]^2  (\[Phi]')^2) + 
      r^2  \[Eta]^2  Sin[\[Theta]]^2) /. coordrep;

Pt = D[lagrangian, t'[\[Tau]]];

Pr = D[lagrangian, r'[\[Tau]]];

P\[Theta] = D[lagrangian, \[Theta]'[\[Tau]]];

P\[Phi] = D[lagrangian, \[Phi]'[\[Tau]]];

hamiltonian = ((Pt  t'[\[Tau]] + Pr  r'[\[Tau]] + 
         P\[Theta]  \[Theta]'[\[Tau]] + P\[Phi]  \[Phi]'[\[Tau]]) - 
       lagrangian) /. t'[\[Tau]] -> En /. \[Phi]'[\[Tau]] -> l // 
   Expand;

lag = lagrangian /. t'[\[Tau]] -> En /. \[Phi]'[\[Tau]] -> l;

Needs["VariationalMethods`"]

eqns = EulerEquations[lag, {r[\[Tau]], \[Theta][\[Tau]]}, \[Tau]];

f[r_] = 1 + r^2/(4  \[Lambda]) - 
   r^2/(4  \[Lambda])  Sqrt[
     1 + (8  \[Lambda]  (rh^2 + rh^4 + 2  \[Lambda]))/r^4 - 
      8  \[Lambda]];

En = 20; \[Alpha] = 
 1/\[Pi]; \[Eta] = 1; l = 10; rh = 1; \[Lambda] = -0.1;

sol = Table[
   Block[{a, b, \[Chi], d, habd}, 
    habd = hamiltonian /. \[Tau] -> 0 /. {r[0] -> a, 
       r'[0] -> b, \[Theta][0] -> \[Chi], \[Theta]'[0] -> d}; {a, 
      b, \[Chi]} = {x, 5, 0}; d = d /. FindRoot[habd == En, {d, x}];
    Reap[
     Quiet@NDSolve[{eqns, r[0] == a, 
        r'[0] == b, \[Theta][0] == \[Chi], \[Theta]'[0] == 
         d}, {\[Theta][\[Tau]], \[Theta]'[\[Tau]]}, {\[Tau], 0, 5000},
        Method -> Automatic, MaxSteps -> 5  10^4, 
       MaxStepSize -> .5]]], {x, 10, 11, 0.2}];
kol = Flatten[sol[[1, 1]], 1];

ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate[{\[Theta][\[Tau]], \[Theta]'[\[Tau]]} /. kol], {\[Tau], 0, 
  10}, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
 AxesLabel -> {"\[Theta]", "\[Theta]'"}]


It is clear that we can use $\theta'$, for example in a form
sol1 = Table[
   Block[{a, b, \[Chi], d, habd}, 
    habd = hamiltonian /. \[Tau] -> 0 /. {r[0] -> a, 
       r'[0] -> b, \[Theta][0] -> \[Chi], \[Theta]'[0] -> d}; {a, 
      b, \[Chi]} = {x, 5, 0}; d = d /. FindRoot[habd == En, {d, x}];
    Reap[
     Quiet@NDSolve[{eqns, r[0] == a, 
        r'[0] == b, \[Theta][0] == \[Chi], \[Theta]'[0] == d, 
        WhenEvent[\[Theta]'[\[Tau]] - 17 == 0, 
         Sow[{r[\[Tau]], r'[\[Tau]]}]]}, {}, {\[Tau], 0, 5000}, 
       MaxSteps -> 10^5, MaxStepSize -> .5]]], {x, 10, 11, 0.2}];

Visualization
ps = ListPlot[Table[Flatten[sol1[[i]][[2]], 1], {i, Length@sol1}], 
  PlotTheme -> {"Detailed", "NeonColor"}, FrameLabel -> {r, r'}, 
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[.01], LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 20], 
  PlotRange -> All]



Thank you for the clarification, Alex. I was trying to reproduce Figure 2 of this paper, and they write the conditions to be theta=0 and ptheta>0.  What modifications needs to be done in the code for that?

@codebpr Sorry, but your code nothing to do with the problem considered in the paper you cited. :)

Apologies for that. I will post a new question in this regard.

@codebpr Please, pay attention that they used H=0, and not H=En as in your code. Also, they fixed r[0]==5, pr[0]== 2.670855 and $\theta(0)=0$ as input data. Try to derive system (22)-(26) from the paper instead of yours.
